# Handle when method returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm starting with using Spring Boot and Java I would like to know how to handle when a method returns null.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;
    ......

}


@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findOneByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }
}
```

In `UserService` I would like to know how to handle the situation where the method `findByUsername` returns `null`. I should use something like this. Now, when the user is not found, it throws an exception.

```
UserDetails u = userRepository.findOneByUsername(username);
if(u === null) 
  return...
else
  return u;
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your repository method always returns an Optional, and your service method either it returns UserDetails, or throws an exception, but never returns null. So, what exactly is the question?

Comment: @JB Nizet how to handle it when don't using optional?

Comment: Well, you check for null before dereferencing the returned value, otherwise you get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

I understood the question so that you have this:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return userRepository.findOneByUsername(username)
      .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
}
```

but findOneByUsername() can return null. In that case, some options are

- use `Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findOneByUsername(username))` which will force null result to Optional.empty, so you can keep the construct you now have:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
  Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findOneByUsername(username))
      .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
}
```

- explicitly check for null, throw the new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found") if it happens
- let nullpointerexception happen. On some cases this is feasible, but since you apparently want to have UsernameNotFoundException thrown if user is not found, it wouldn't work here.
- change your underlying code to throw an exception if result is not found. That would probably be my choice, as nulls often are receipe for trouble. Some popular frameworks such as [Spring JDBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) and [Spring Data](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-jpa/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-) do this. Since you're already using Spring, I would heavily recommend following the same pattern.

TLDR; could you just change the underlying code to throw an exception if the object is not found?